# Pronunciation of "again"

Tags: pronunciation, adverbs, received-pronunciation

What is the Standard British English<sup>1</sup> pronunciation of "again"? I looked in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/again) and it gives two UK pronunciations, /əˈɡeɪn/, and /əˈɡɛn/.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I mean Standard British English as in the [tag description](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/received-pronunciation/info) for `received-pronunciation`: "Received Pronunciation (RP) is the prestigious and non-regional variety of British English often considered to be Standard British English."</sup>

Comment: There are two pronunciations given because both are valid in their own circumstances. /əˈɡɛn/ is probably more widely used.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks! Should I interpret your "circumstances" such that a _single_ SBE-speaker might use _both_ pronunciations, but each in different circumstances? Or rather that there are two groups of SBE-speakers, with each a different (but consistent) pronunciation?

Comment: Probably the first. Actually, in a cut-glass RP accent (think 1940s BBC Overseas Service) the difference between the two forms is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

I looked in [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/again_1?q=again) and they give us two pronunciations for **British English**:

> /əˈɡen/ /-ˈɡeɪn/

And for **American English**:

> /-ˈɡen/

Comment: In my question, I meant Standard British English as in the tag description for received-pronunciation: "Received Pronunciation (RP) is the prestigious and non-regional variety of British English often considered to be Standard British English."